# PHP errors parsing Realurl config file

Tags: php, typo3

I have installed the typo3 rearurl extension in Typo3. If I copy to the default manual config location `typo3conf/realurl_conf.php` a configuration file with for example:

```
<?PHP
   $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
      '_DEFAULT' => array(

      ),
   );
?>
```

I getting PHP errors like below?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$TYPO3_CONF_VARS' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/extension/public_html/typo3conf/realurl_conf.php on line 1
```

Comment: What is the code before file inclusion?

Comment: This is the complete config file and then the PHP errors are already generated

Comment: THis file is included somewhere, right? Where?

Comment: In the extension manager I go the the realurl extension and then there is the default path to `typo3conf/realurl_conf.php` so I suppose it is included there.

Comment: BTW wriye which version of TYPO3 and RealURL ext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead

```
<?PHP
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
   '_DEFAULT' => array(

   ),
);
?>
```

In newer version there are some problems with `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS` vs `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']` the last one works always.

Comment: I'm getting exact the same error with this config file. But I believe this is not a typo3 error but a PHP error. Looks like the parser is not expecting a php file. I'm not understanding why it is not expecting a php file?

Comment: You can check the file by calling it directly, i.e. `http://yourdomain.loc/typo3conf/realurl_conf.php` also check if there at no any hidden characters.

Comment: There where hidden characters in my file by removing them it is solved, thanks.